# Rails Model error unknown attribute on save with belongs_to and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wasn't to understand how the model on Rails works when you setup the relations with plural or non-plural.

Example:

We have this model called "Cliente".

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sucursales
end
```

The table on MySQL is:

[image]

And we have the model called "Sucursale":

```
class Sucursale < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cliente
end
```

The table is:

[image]

On the table sucursale already has "clientes_id" that was created with a migration "t.belongs_to :clientes, index: true.

On our simple crud, we want to create a new Sucursale with the client relation with:

```
def create
        @sucursalcliente = Cliente.find(params[:clientes_id])
        @sucursalcliente.sucursales.build(
            :nombre => params[:nombre], 
            :calle => params[:calle],
            :numero_interior => params[:numero_interior],
            :numero_exterior => params[:numero_exterior],
            :colonia => params[:colonia],
            :municipio => params[:municipio],
            :estado => params[:estado],
            :pais => params[:pais],
            :codigo_postal => params[:codigo_postal],
            :email => params[:email],
            :telefono => params[:telefono]
        )])
        if @sucursalcliente.save
            flash[:info] = 'Sucursal creado correctamente'
            redirect_to action: 'index'
        else
            flash[:alert] = 'Error al crear la sucursal'
            redirect_to action: 'index'
        end
    end
```

But when we run that script we get.

```
unknown attribute 'cliente_id' for Sucursale.
```

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unknown attribute 'cliente_id' for Sucursale.

The problem is that `t.belongs_to :clientes, index: true` generates the column name as `clientes_id` **not** `cliente_id`

**Solution:**

You can choose to **rollback the migration**, edit the code in the migration file as

```
t.belongs_to :cliente, index: true
```

and migrate it again.

*OR*

If you choose not to rollback the migration, then specify the custom `foreign_key` on the association to override the default behavior of Rails.

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sucursales, foreign_key: :clientes_id
end
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, even with the foreign_key on Sucursale model, i get the same error.
`unknown attribute 'cliente_id' for Sucursale.`

Comment: @Ulises My apologies. It should be in `Cliente` model. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried on the two ways and works fine, thanks a lot, so on the migration always need to set in on non-plural, i supouse the belongs_to on the migration is a helper and doesn't validate if the sintaxis for the model name are correct